# Converge of distance between two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ be sequences in the metric space $(X,d).$ Suppose $s_n \rightarrow s \in X$ and $t_n \rightarrow t \in X.$ Prove that $d(s_n,t_n) \rightarrow d(s,t).$

My attempt: Assume $s_n \rightarrow s \in X$ and $t_n \rightarrow t \in X.$ Then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ $N$ such that $n>N \implies d(s_n,s) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ And  $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ $M$ such that $m>M \implies d(t_m,t) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Now let $K=max\{N,M\}$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ $K$ such that $n>K \implies d(s_n,t_n) \le d(s_n,s)+d(t_n,t)< \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$

Does this look correct? It's the only way I could think to try it. Thanks

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But he seems to have shown that $d(s_n,t_n)\to0$.

Comment: @Harald: Oops: I didn’t register the missing term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but didn't quite carry it out properly.

Hint: Work with triangle inequalities in two directions.
$$ d(s_n,t_n)\le d(s_n,s)+d(s,t)+d(t,t_n)$$
and
$$ d(s,t)\le d(s,s_n)+d(s_n,t_n)+d(t_n,t)$$
and see what happens when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Then don't I need a value in terms of $\epsilon$ for $d(s,t)$?

Comment: I don't understand why you think that. If $n$ is large enough, you get $d(s_n,s)<\epsilon/2$ and $d(t_n,t)<\epsilon/2$. Just apply those to the right hand sides in the answer and see what you get! (How big an $n$ is needed is of course determined by the given sequences. But nowhere does $d(s,t)$ enter into that consideration, that I can see.)